# Not able to find a file residing two directories up

Tags: permissions, apache2, php

Currently, my directory's structure looks like this:

```
- project
 - app
  - Config
   - file1.php
 - file.txt
```

This project folder is in `/var/www/html` folder. I am including `file.txt` in `file1.php` using the following code.

```
require_once '../../file.txt';
```

**The Problem is, it can't find the file even when it is there.** This is working on my local system which has Ubuntu 18.04, but not on the server that has Ubuntu 19.04. The project is built using the CakePHP framework.

```
$ ls -ld /var/www/html/project /var/www/html/project/app \
         /var/www/html/project/app/Config /var/www/html/project/file.txt
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root 4096 May 30 11:01 /var/www/html/project
drwxrwxr-x 13 root root 4096 May 29 08:09 /var/www/html/project/app
drwxrwxr-x  3 root root 4096 May 30 05:29 /var/www/html/project/app/Config
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3401 May 30 11:13 /var/www/html/project/file.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to me to be a difference in `php`'s current working directory. The working system has `.../project/app/Config` as the current directory while the broken system has `.../project` as the current directory.

One workaround would be to determine the `file1.php`'s current directory and then refer to `file.txt` with a relative path from *there*. If I use this in `file1.php`, it correctly includes `file.txt`:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../file.txt');
```